# Calling a generator function from a client that performs asynchronous calls in a loop using Promises

Tags: javascript

I need to crawl the entire DOM from top to bottom processing each node. When a node meets certain criteria, I then need to process information about that node synchronously, meaning that I don't continue on to the next node in the DOM until the processing work has completed.

The processing of a node involves multiple ajax calls and I would like to carry out these calls asynchronously. Only after all ajax calls have completed, can the final processing work be done and the result returned back to the point in my DOM crawling.

The solution I am leaning towards is to create a generator function that does the crawling of the DOM and then executes the yield statement when the node with the criteria has been met and the contents of that node are transferred back to the client (via the yield statement) that called the next function.

The client that initiated the call to the generator function will then parse the node's data, create multiple Promises and execute all these promises asynchronously with Promise.all().

Once all promises have completed and the processing has finished, the generator function is called again but this time the processed data from the client is returned to where the yield statement left off which will then merge this back into the DOM.

What isn't clear to me is how to create the client code that performs the node processing which includes executing the promises. If possible, I would like to avoid recursively calling the client function. Here is some pseudo code I can imagine being done:

Generator:

```
function *crawlDOM() {
  let node = "html";

  function processNode(node) {
    if (node.value == "someCriteria") {
      let processedValue = yield node.value;
      // Do something with the processed value...
    }

    for (let i = 0; i < node.children.length; i++) {
      processNode(node.children[i]);
    }
  }
}
```

Node processing client:

```
function processNodeData() {
    var crawler = crawlDOM();
    var processedData = "";

    while (true) {
       var nodeData = crawler.next(processedData).value;
       var items[] = nodeData.split("\n");
       var promises[] = [items.length];

       for (let i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
          promises[i] = new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
             // Do some work
             resolve(result);
          }
       }

       Promises.all(promises)
         .then(function(result) {
            processedData = "some new data";
            // Do some final processing.
            // At this point, we need to call the generator function again but with the processed data.
            // But this is the wrong place to do it because the "while" loop will have already moved on
            // to the next node while this "then" code is being executed.
         })

    }
}
```

How do I resolve the looping issue so that the next call to the generator function only occurs after the Promise.all() has completed?

Comment: do you use node?  there is neat lib,, `npm install co` GH repo is here.. take a look => https://github.com/tj/co

Comment: @KresimirPendic Thanks for the link but that code seems outdated and hasn't seen commit in almost a year. The solution I came up with below is pretty simple and solves the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The key to executing Promises in a loop is to place those promises inside an async function:

```
function processNode(x) {
    return new Promise(resolve => {
        setTimeout(() => {
            resolve(x);
        }, 2000);
    });
}

async function startNodeProcessing() {
    while(true) {
        var a = processNode(20);
        var b = processNode(30);
        var r = await a + await b;
    }

    return;
}
startNodeProcessing();
```

The line of code:

```
var r = await a + await b;
```

blocks until all promises have completed. This means that you don't need Promise.all, although you probably could still use that. After the blocking has completed, you can just continue repeating the loop. There is no recursive calling and the blocking is native to the async function meaning that you are not blocking the main thread, so you won't see any UI issues if you have lengthy code in the loop to process.